# Add text under an equation in Office

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to achieve this in Microsoft Word.

[image]

This is what I managed to do:

[image]

How can I add the text below the reaction? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using a matrix layout with 3 vertical squares to line up the text for each "segment" of your equation?

Answer (score 1):

The matrix is a good option, although you could also use the \ below command and add the characters you need below each compound, something like this:

```
C_12[SP]H_26[SP]\below[SP](“gogekaH”)[SP]\below(T_K[SP]=69 °C)[SP]
```

with `[SP]`=Space. Using Word equation tools you can record the

Lineal form:

```
〖C_12 H_26〗┬(〖"gogekaH" 〗┬(T_K=216 °C) )⟶〖C_6 H_14〗┬(〖"xekcaH" 〗┬(T_k=69 °C) )+〖C_6 H_12〗┬(〖"xekceH" 〗┬(T_k=64 °C) )
```

Professional form:

[image: professional]